# Test for registration system for Symfony2 using Behat and Mink

Tags: symfony, tdd, bdd, behat, mink

My question is related with the tests for some application in Symfony2. I use the Behat and Mink to write the tests and I have some problems with tests for registration system.

I want to check the email after user submit the registration form and then follow the activation link in this email.

I found a short tutorial about the tests for emails:
http://docs.behat.org/cookbook/using_the_profiler_with_minkbundle.html

Solution in this tutorial works only if the "intercept_redirects" is set to "true" in configuration file for symfony but I already have some tests where I need to leave this variable with "false", so my question is... is it possible to change this value temporary, only for one test or do I have to change this value to "true" and then update all the tests?

How do you test your registration systems, and how do you write the tests for them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [MinkRedirectContext](https://github.com/Behat/CommonContexts/blob/master/Behat/CommonContexts/MinkRedirectContext.php) from [CommonContexts](https://github.com/Behat/CommonContexts). It allows you to stop automatic redirections for a scenario and inspect the URL:

```
Given I do not follow redirects
 When I ...
 Then I should be redirected to "/thank-you"
```

You could also do it manually by calling *followRedirects()* yourself:

```
$this->getSession()->getDriver()->getClient()->followRedirects(false);
```